# How, I can change password, if I do not know the old password?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, owin

I need create method, which can change password in database if I do not know the old password. For example, I have next code:

```
      public IHttpActionResult ChangePassword(ChangePasswordBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var result = UserManager.ChangePassword(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword,
            model.NewPassword);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

In this code need  "model.OldPassword" but User don't know old password.
I have only password and current user id.

Comment: Can I use "PasswordHasher.HashPassword" for my example?

Comment: So you want someone who doesn't know the password to be able to change it to a new one that they *can* use, right? And you can't see any problems with that? Anyway, doing this should be an admin function - someone who knows the admin password can change another user's password.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I see where you are going but what if OP would do it with a mail verification or something like that?

Comment: @maam27 That would be ok, but it would be a server-side function (so no password required to send out the email and respond to the user's reply by allowing them to enter a new password).

Comment: Yes of course. Only administrator can change password.

Comment: Ah, then see Spender's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I have no idea whether this is optimal, but it's pretty easy.

First:

```
var code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(userId);
```

then

```
var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(userId, code, someNewPassword);
```

You could even wrap it up in an extension method

```
public static class UserManagerEx
{
    public static async Task<IdentityResult> ForceChangePassword<T, TUserId>(
        this UserManager<T, TUserId> userManager,
        TUserId userId,
        string newPassword)
            where T : class, IUser<TUserId>
            where TUserId : IEquatable<TUserId>
    {
        var code = await userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(userId);
        var result = await userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(userId, code, newPassword);
        return result;
    }
}
```

then call it:

```
var result = UserManager.ForceChangePassword(userId, newPassword);
```